# How do Amazon Elasticsearch and Elastic Cloud (elastic.co) compare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I need to choose between the two services (or managing a cluster myself) with high availability and high update rate. Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

Elastic.co has a nice article that has a comparison which is kept up to date:

[elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service](http://elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service)

But ofcourse this is not impartial advice.
What is best depends on your needs.

In general Elastic.co is more expensive than AWS and AWS is more expensive than doing it yourself.
Doing it yourself is most flexible, but takes a lot of work and expertise.
AWS good when you're already on AWS and want to connect to their services, but offers less features and is somewhat behind.
Elastic.co gives the best service and features appart from AWS integration.

So to summarize: Do it yourself if you need a lot of flexibility and are not pressed for time and resources. Else choose AWS when you're already on AWS and don't need the latest version and features. Else choose Elastic Cloud.

Comment: the up-to-date link is https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service

Answer (score -1):

One of the main differences is that to date only the elastic.co service allows provide **ElasticSearch 2.x.** With the AWS offer you only can use **ElasticSearch 1.x.** Which is to date actually already quite behind. In general high update rate or high availability should be achievable with both services and also more depends on how you structure your cluster and which nodes you choose. Price-wise IMHO the AWS offering is cheaper. Elastic.co allows to have their own advanced tools like Marvel to be included.